# phpolait framework JSONRpcProxy function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, class, frameworks

Hi stackoverflow nation , reason of being here is php framework published at 2006 called phpolait (can be downloaded from [phpolait](http://www.phpkode.com/projects/item/phpolait/), and documentation can be seen from 
[documentation](http://phpolait.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html))

if anyone is using or have an idea how function **JSONRpcProxy** works may help to solve a little problem.

First of all in my web root dir I've directory named /test/ where I've placed phpolait framework. and there I'm creating files info.php and function.php

info.php source =>

```
<?php
require_once("./phpolait/phpolait.php");
$proxy = new JSONRpcProxy("http://127.0.0.1/test/function.php");

echo $proxy->power(2,2);
?>
```

function.php source =>

```
class Math{
    public function power($x,$y){
        return pow($x,$y);
    }
    public function fact($x){
        if ($x==0){
        return 1;
        } else {
            $x *= $this->fact($x-1);
        }
        return $x;
    }
};

new JSONRpcServer(new Math());
```

when trying to access in info.php file it gets up array =>

`Array ( [0] => [1] => JSON-RPC call failed. [2] => )`

I've been read documentation but how you see I'm missing something important , so if anyone have any touch in this framework may give me a hand , I'll be very pleased , thanks :)

PS. And also interested any alternatives of phpolait framework which continues improving , at least has renewed versions

Comment: Is that RPC URL referencing your function definition script directly? Does this work?. I see you register it with the according handler/dispatcher, but can it get instantiated there? Do you load the required framework/base classes before? What do you get if you access the functions script in your browser?

Comment: @mario now I've tested what you have mentioned (I mean inserted framework in function.php too ) , now in info.php it gets up array like this => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => )

Comment: @mario you're right , because without including framework in function.php file it was server error, cuz not declaring JSONRpcServer function

Comment: @mario thanks for helping , by the way don't you know any similar framework which has at least new versions ?